# extracting pcap name from a string using shell script or gawk

Tags: shell, awk, gawk

i have a file pcap_list which contains the path of several pcap files for eg.

```
./folder1/folder2/...../foldern/sample1.pcap
./folder1/folder2/...../foldern/sample2.pcap    and so on....
```

from this i want to extract the name of pcap files using shell script in linux. can anyone let me know how i can do that . Though when i used 
    gawk 'BEGIN {FS = "/"} {print $NF}' pcap_list
it worked fine. but i want to do this in a loop and wrote the following script for that.

```
#!/bin/bash
PCAP_LIST=$1
count=0
cat $PCAP_LIST | while read PCAP_PATH
do
        let count++
        echo "$count $PCAP_PATH"
pcapname=($(gawk -v pcappath=$PCAP_PATH 'BEGIN {FS = "/"} {print $NF}' pcappath))
printf "pcapname =$pcapname"
done
```

it is not working. can anyone let me know how i can do that.
any help will be greatly appreciated. thanks.

Comment: UUOC: while read PCAP_PATH; do ... done < $PCAP_LIST

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's not working is that you're using a variable name incorrectly on your `gawk` command. As it is, it's trying to process a file called, literally, "pcappath". The variable passing argument makes the variable available *inside* the `gawk` script, *not* as a filename argument.

In your question, you say "it is not working", but you don't say how or include any error messages. If you had, it probably gives information as to what the problem is.

Regardless, fixing the problem is simple.

You can use `basename` as Mechanical snail suggests, or you can fix your `gawk` version (which I show below), or you can use a pure Bash version (which I show below that).

```
pcapname=$(echo "$PCAP_PATH" | gawk 'BEGIN {FS = "/"} {print $NF}')
```

Also, there's no reason to use the extra set of parentheses to create an array.

Here's a pure Bash version:

```
#!/bin/bash
pcap_list=$1
count=0
while read -r pcap_path
do
    (( count++ ))
    echo "$count $PCAP_PATH"
    pcapname=${pcappath##*/}
    printf '%s\n' "pcapname = $pcapname"
done < "$pcap_list"
```

You should habitually use lower case or mixed case variable names in order to reduce the chance of name collision with shell or environment variables.

Don't use `cat` for this application - simply redirect the file into the `done` statement. One advantage is that this avoids creating a subshell so your variables retain their values after the `while` loop is completed.

The `-r` option of `read` should almost always be used. This causes `read` to accept backslashes literally.

Use `(())` instead of `let` since it's more flexible.

Use parameter expansion to extract the basename.

Your `printf` (presumably) needed a newline.

Answer (score 1):

This is easy using the `basename` command:

```
cat $PCAP_LIST | while read PCAP_PATH ; do basename "$PCAP_PATH" ; done
```